# Selenium click at text field fails during test, passes single command test

Tags: selenium, windows-10

I'm using the selenium plug in, through firefox, i have a test case set up to do a search through some fields, the problem is that when the page loads to the search screen its failing the click at command to the text field. it then fails to edit the text in the field obviously.

This command passes though if i test the single command after the test initially fails. then it allows the text to be edited.

Unfortunately I can not give to much info about the site or the page, its proprietary. I can provide some screen grabs of the commands failing though (this is a lie i need 10 rep to post images) sorry. Any info that can explain why this is happening would great though.

the last commands to pass are as follows:
click at xpath=(//a (its a link)
pause for 3000 ms

fails here: 
click at id=searchName 85,17

This is the error message: Trying to find id=searchName... Failed:
Implicit Wait timed out after 30000ms

it brings up the link and after the pause it fails, i allowed the pause to give the full page time to load. It doesn't seem to help at all. Again it will run the command it i test the single command on the page immediately after i stop the test

Edit: html code for the element being searched

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter full name or organization name..." 
name="search" id="searchName" value="Mr And Mrs Ronald J Ulrich"   autofocus="" type="text">
```

edit2:if i switch the item being searched to name=search i get a different error:

type on name=search with value Ronald J Ulrich... Failed:
Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Comment: It would be awesome, if you show us your code and relevant HTML

Comment: Test your xpath in chrome console and see if it finds the element.

Comment: The 'code' you gave says nothing. Provide a normal code you used, it is impossible to help James Bond

Comment: added html code for the element trying to be found also im not using webdriver but the plug in for mozilla, there is no code other than the pages html just the display window. and when i enter "id=searchName in the console in firefox and chrome it finds the element just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like i was missing a select window command before trying to click and edit the element. Being new to this platform I wasn't taking into consideration any new tabs that we're opening. It failed the overall test due to opening a new tab and not having the select window command. Thanks folks.